# Flutter use changed date in a other widget

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, data-transfer

I've got two stateful widgets. In one widget I got an actual date in DateTime, which I change with a click on a Button.
I want to use the changed date in the second Widget. I want to achieve this with the Provider in which I save the actual date in a variable. This variable I want to call in the second widget, so I can use the use the changed date in that widget. But I'm not sure, wether this is the best option or how to call the function so that only the date is returned.

the provider class DateModel:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DateModel with ChangeNotifier {
  var dateGeneral = DateTime(
    DateTime.now().year,
    DateTime.now().month,
    DateTime.now().day,
    DateTime.now().weekday,
  );

  DateTime actualSavedDate(DateTime actualTime) {
    DateTime actualSavedTime = actualTime;
    actualSavedTime.day;
    return actualSavedTime;
  }

  DateTime monatHigher(DateTime actualHigherDate) {
    DateTime dateHigherMonth = DateTime(
      DateTime.now().year,
      actualHigherDate.month + 1,
      DateTime.now().day,
      DateTime.now().weekday,
    );
    notifyListeners();
    return dateHigherMonth;
  }

  DateTime monatLower(DateTime actualLowerMonth) {
    DateTime dateLowerMonth = DateTime(
      DateTime.now().year,
      actualLowerMonth.month - 1,
      DateTime.now().day,
      DateTime.now().weekday,
    );
    notifyListeners();
    return dateLowerMonth;
  }
}
```

the widget in which the date is changed;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';
import 'package:dart_date/dart_date.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../provider/date_model.dart';

class MonatUmschalt extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MonatUmschaltState createState() => _MonatUmschaltState();
}

class _MonatUmschaltState extends State<MonatUmschalt> {
  DateTime actualDate = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dateData = Provider.of<DateModel>(context);
    dateData.actualSavedDate(actualDate);
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            actualDate = dateData.monatLower(actualDate);
            dateData.actualSavedDate(actualDate);
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_left_sharp),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.amber[600],
          width: 100,
          height: 40.0,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              //(actualDate == dateChangedMonth)
              // ? dateChangedMonth.format('MMMM yyyy', 'de_DE')
              /*:*/ actualDate.format('MMMM yyyy', 'de_DE'),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            actualDate = dateData.monatHigher(actualDate);
            dateData.actualSavedDate(actualDate);
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_right_sharp),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I think the second widget is not necessary, because in this I just want to use the changed date. But every time it is changed in the first widget, the date has to be updated in the second.

Thank your for your help

Best regards
Patrick

Comment: The logic is not very clear, can you share a workable code of the two pages?

Comment: I edited my post with a view more code

Comment: I think there should be no problem with the method you use. [Doc - simple state managemetn in flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) introduced this. Select which state management method depends on your project. If it's just a simple demo, you may just construct the second page with the `actualDate`

Comment: value got from the first page, or you can store it in local storage and get the value on the second page. The `provider` is a more systematic way and if you think it is not too verbose for your project then you can use it (and there are also many other more verbose state management frameworks you can give it a try).